# How to get the application terminated notification quickly cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications

To get the application terminated notification I have something like the following

```
 NSNotificationCenter*  center = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];

    [center addObserver:self 
               selector:@selector(appTerminated:) 
                   name:NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification 
                 object:nil
     ];




- (void)appTerminated:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSLog(@"+ appTerminated");
}
```

actually my concern is when the firefox application quits/restarts,I need to update its database.When the firefox quits manually I can update with the help of appTerminated as firefox releasing its lock to the database.When it is running state,I am not able to update the database as firefox is locking it.when the firefox is restarted ,it is quitting and restarting too quickly so that I cannot update the database as it is in running stateI need to update database before it restarts.i.e.when the firefox is in quit state.

So,I need the notification just before firefox is going to quit.
Is any api availabe for this or please give some ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Core Data?

Answer (score 2):

I take it you have two applications, one that watches the other. Your concern seems to be that you don't want the watched app to start really doing anything until the watcher finishes its work.

You just need to communicate between the processes in this case. The watched application should wait until the watcher finishes its work. You can achieve this using a lock, or you could use `NSDistributedNotification` (or other IPC mechanism) to send messages from the watcher to the watched to let it know it may continue.

I prefer the locking mechanism since it behaves correctly if the watcher fails. The most correct place to put the lock would be on the database, since that's the resource you're trying to protect.

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like that:

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    if (isMyDatabaseClosed) {
         [self closeMyDatabaseAndQuit];
         return NSTerminateLater;
    } else {
         return NSTerminateNow;
    }
}

-(void)closeMyDatabaseAndQuit 
{
/* close your database, etc...*/
    [NSApp replyToApplicationShouldTerminate: YES];
}
```

The code is not tested, but you should get an idea.